# Custom jQuery Plugin Possible Variable Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, animation, plugins

Creating my own jQuery plugin to handle image sequences. Everything works perfectly when there is only one image sequence going on. However, when I have 2 image sequences on the page at once (both with infinite looping), the smaller of the 2 image sequences stops prematurely. It reaches it's 2nd loop and always stops at frame 34 (out of 38). I think this might be an issue where the 2nd sequence is grabbing from the variables of the first, but I'm not sure. Everything works great up to this, so I am not sure. Here is the code below, sorry if it's a lot to take in.

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.createSequence = function( sequence ) {
        var container = this;
        var dir = sequence.dir;
        var name = sequence.name;
        var extension = sequence.extension;
        var start = sequence.start;
        var end = sequence.end;
        var fps = 1000 / sequence.fps;
        var trailing = sequence.trailing || true;
        var digits = sequence.digits;
        var loopType = sequence.loopType || 'none';
        var loopAmount = sequence.loopAmount || 'infinite';
        this.currentLoop = 0;
        var zeroes = '';
        var reverse = false;

        // Prepare current frame using starting frame
        var currentFrame = start;

        // Function for adding trailing zeroes
        function calcTrailing(amount){
            zeroes = '';
            for ( i = 0; i < amount; i++ ) {
                zeroes = zeroes + '0';
            }
        }

        // Prepare zeroes variable based on number of digits
        if (trailing) {
            calcTrailing(digits);
        }

        // Build full source
        var fullSource = dir + name + zeroes + extension;

        // Append first frame to container
        container.append('<img src="' + fullSource + '" />');

        // Put added img element into variable for use
        var imgElement = container.children('img');

        // Change img src
        function changeSrc(frameNumber) {
            fullSource = dir + name + zeroes + frameNumber + extension;
            imgElement.attr('src', fullSource);
        }

        // Go to next frame
        function nextFrame() {
            if (reverse) {
                if (currentFrame == start) {
                    ++this.currentLoop;
                    reverse = false;
                    clearInterval(animation);
                    restartAnimation();
                } else {
                    --currentFrame;
                }
            } else {
                ++currentFrame;
            }
            if ( currentFrame > end ) {
                if ( loopType == 'none' ) {
                    clearInterval(animation);
                } else if ( loopType == 'restart' ) {
                    ++this.currentLoop;
                    if ( loopAmount == 'infinite' || this.currentLoop < loopAmount ) {
                        currentFrame = start;
                    }
                } else if ( loopType == 'reverse' ) {
                    reverse = true;
                    --currentFrame;
                }
            } else if ( currentFrame < 10 ) {
                calcTrailing(digits - 1);
                changeSrc(currentFrame);
            } else if ( currentFrame < 100 ) {
                calcTrailing(digits - 2);
                changeSrc(currentFrame);
            }
        }

        // Start the image sequence
        function animateSequence() {
            animation = setInterval(nextFrame, fps);
        }

        // Restart animation
        function restartAnimation() {
            if ( loopAmount == 'infinite' || this.currentLoop < loopAmount ) {
                animation = setInterval(nextFrame, fps);
            }
        }

        animateSequence();
    }
}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: Have you tried using `return this.each(function () { ... }` to wrap the  content of the function?

Comment: I tried it earlier and it made everything stop working completely. Will try again in a minute.

Comment: Figured out why it was causing it to not work earlier, my `container` variable was defined as `this` instead of `$(this)` which doesn't work in the each function. However, wrapping everything in `return this.each(function () { ... }` Causes the same problem I am originally having. Animation1 loops infinitely as intended, but animation 2 reaches the 2nd loop and stops at frame 34/38.

Comment: If it helps at all, I slowed the animation down and watched it frame by frame to figure out the issue. Animation1 goes from frames 0 to 60 then back down to 0 as it's supposed to. When it reaches back to 0, Animation2 is at frame 34 and stops (because Animation1 reached it's start). Not sure the fix for this issue as of now.

Comment: Okay, I changed the name for my restart animation setInterval to animation2 and this sort of fixed my issue. The issue now is the animations exponentially go up in speed now. What would be a good way to go about starting and stopping the setIntervals without calling the other animations?